# Action Bar disappeared when changing Action Bar colour

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to change the colour of my action bar.

I have placed the following code into the styles.xml file:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#a4dba3</item>
</style>
```

I have then gone into the android manifest file and entered the following, as I want the action bar to be the same across all my activities:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
```

I have run the emulator and noticed that the action bar has disappeared.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: I believe you would only get that error if you had it as `android:theme="MyCustomTheme"` (without the @style). Are you sure you have it as you do in the question?

Comment: yes I have it how it is above

Comment: and you're still getting that error? The error is saying that the attribute `theme` has a value of `MyCustomTheme` that is invalid. Unless I'm wrong about that but I'm pretty sure that's what the error means.

Comment: your'e right I don't seem to get the error any more, strange as it was as above.  I now notice that when I run the emulator the action bar has totally dissappeared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent style you set for `MyActionBarTheme` should be

`@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar`

or equivalent like so:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#a4dba3</item>
</style>
```

Since you just had it set to the Holo Light Theme, there were essentially no styles for the actual action bar.

For more info click [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground), especially if targeting under API 11.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code in styles.xml

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="ActionBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background_i</item>
</style>

    <style name="ETheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/customActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/NoCloseButton</item> 
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item> 
    <!-- <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/item_selector_background</item>
     <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@color/action_button_pressed</item> -->

</style>


    <style name="customActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">

    <item name="android:background">#15a9f6</item>
   <!--<item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/actionbarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title</item> -->
</style>

    <style name="NoCloseButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

add the following in Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ETheme" >
```

Comment: I have done as you have stated, but i now get the following error:error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@drawable/
 actionbar_background_i').

Do I need to setup a drawable file as well?

Comment: yes.. you need to replace the drawable files that I used

Comment: you can use your own drawables, if you need, I can publish them too